# How to preload XML data into Core Data/iCloud integrated app with Swift?

Tags: xml, swift, core-data, ios9, icloud

Hey guys I am working on a project that uses Core Data with iCloud integration. The project is a simple tableview with an add button that loads an Alert with a Textfield and the user input is displayed on the tableview up "Ok" button pressed.

This app is based on the EZiCloud template contained in the book "Learning Core Data for iOS with Swift" by Tim Roadley.

I am coming here because the writer does does not provide ANY support since there´s no contact on the book, or on his site or even a Forum... So, that´s why I am coming here.

The problem is that the app is to preload load 3 default items before the user uses the app. It works fine if use Core Data only and do the preload by importing an XML file with the default data as Chapter 8 from the book teaches.

But after integrating iCloud into the project the book just says nothing about the preloading data or even how to integrate the XML preloading already existed on the project with iCloud.

So, I wonder if anyone here have an idea of how I could do this.

Here´s is the code that sets up CoraData/iCloud:

```
func setupCoreData() {

    /*// Model Migration
     if let _localStoreURL = self.localStoreURL {
     CDMigration.shared.migrateStoreIfNecessary(_localStoreURL, destinationModel: self.model)
     } */

    // Load Local Store
    self.setDefaultDataStoreAsInitialStore()
    //_ = self.sourceStore
    _ = self.localStore

    // Load iCloud Store
    if let _ = self.iCloudStore {

        // self.destroyAlliCloudDataForThisApplication()

        //            if let path = self.seedStoreURL?.path {
        //                // Merge existing data with iCloud
        //                if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        //                    if let _ = self.seedStore {
        //                        self.confirmMergeWithiCloud()
        //                    } else {print("Failed to instantiate seed store")}
        //                } else {print("Failed to find seed store at '\(path)'")}
        //            } else {print("Failed to prepare seed store path")}
        //        } else {print("Failed to load iCloud store")}

        // Import Default Data
        if let _localStoreURL = self.localStoreURL {
            CDImporter.shared.checkIfDefaultDataNeedsImporting(_localStoreURL, type: NSSQLiteStoreType)
        } else {
            print("ERROR getting localStoreURL in \(#function)")}
    }
}
```

Note that the commented code within the "//Load iCloud Store" is related to Deep Copy, which is not to be used when importing from XML file.

So, anyone have an idea how I could do this?